# Specified cast is invalid when using firstordefault

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2012

I am getting "Specified cast is invalid" error at the foreach line when the attached code is run.  I have checked an re-checked all data types in my .dbml vs. the SQL Server (2012) datatypes.  If I remove the linq statement with the firstordefault, the exception is not thrown.  Any ideas, my brain hurts...

```
        // open DB context
        ERAQDataContext db = new ERAQDataContext();

        // get set of Room type Inspection codes
        var RCodes = from v in db.InspectionCodes  
                     where v.CodeType == 'R'
                     select v;            

        // loop thru inspection codes and build table of all codes, checking a checkbox
        // for the ones selected for this inspection.
        foreach (InspectionCode ic in RCodes)
        {
            TableRow tr = new TableRow();
            TableCell tc = new TableCell();
            tc.Style.Add("Width", "25px");
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
            tc.Controls.Add(cb);
            tr.Cells.Add(tc);
            TableCell tc1 = new TableCell();
            tc1.Text = ic.CodeDescription;
            tc1.Style.Add("Width", "150px");
            tr.Cells.Add(tc1);

            // if this code selected on this inspection, check the checkbox and show any comments
            var RCodeComment = (from s in db.RoomCodesViews
                                where s.InspectionCodeId == ic.InspectionCodeId &&
                                s.InspectionId == Convert.ToInt32(fvDetails.DataKey.Value)
                                select s.Comments).FirstOrDefault();

            TableCell tc2 = new TableCell();
            if (RCodeComment != null)
            {
                tc2.Text = Convert.ToString(RCodeComment);
            }
            else
            {
                tc2.Text = "";
            }
            tr.Cells.Add(tc2);
            tbl.Rows.Add(tr);
        }
```

Comment: What is the value of fvDetails.DataKey.Value?

Comment: Marco, the value is 7

Comment: just to confirm, this is using linq-to-sql, correct?  what is the type of s.Comments?  can you post your stack trace

Comment: Does the exception come from the code line `foreach (InspectionCode ic in RCodes)`? Do you realize that there is a cast built into a `foreach` statement? It is almost always a good idea to use the `var` keyword inside a `foreach`, so if you change to `foreach (var ic in RCodes)`, you can see what `var` is (by hovering the mouse over the `var` keyword). However, I don't understand the connection to the `FirstOrDefault` call inside the `foreach` loop.

Comment: The exception does occur at the foreach line.  Yes I know there is a cast in the foreach, in this case a case to InspectionCode, but using var shows that the returned type is indeed InspectionCode, but I get the exception just the same.  It's why my brain hurts :-)

Comment: The exception coming on the foreach line is quandry.  If I comment out the linq statement var RCodeComment = (from s in db.RoomCodesViews...  I no longer get any exception, the foreach does exactly what it should.  The inside linq statement is affecting the foreach in some manner that I cannot understand.  If I run the linq statement var RCodeComment = (from s in db.RoomCodesViews...  outside the foreach (using constants instead of variables), it works with out a hitch.

Answer (score 0):

I belive that using the

```
Convert.ToInt32(fvDetails.DataKey.Value)
```

is not allowed in linq statement

Comment: I believe you are wrong...  I have done it many times successfully.

Comment: hmmm interesting if you are quering against database how would Convert.ToInt32 be translated

Comment: You could easily test this by doing `var detailsKey = fvDetails.DataKey.Value` then  `...s.InspectionId == detailsKey` it means that it won't try and push the conversion into the DB layer.

Comment: Further more if you move that declaration/assignment outside the loop, it will probably be (marginally) better for performance, as you are not performing the same conversion many times.

Comment: I have replaced the Convert statement with a constant value (7) and error is the same.  I have replace the variable ic.InspectionCodeId with a constant value (3) and still have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
from s in db.RoomCodesViews
where s.InspectionCodeId == ic.InspectionCodeId &&
s.InspectionId == Convert.ToInt32(fvDetails.DataKey.Value)
select s.Comments).FirstOrDefault();
```

returns an `IQueryable<RCodeComment>`, not a `RCodeComment`.

```
from s in db.RoomCodesViews
where s.InspectionCodeId == ic.InspectionCodeId &&
s.InspectionId == Convert.ToInt32(fvDetails.DataKey.Value)
from c in s.Comments
select c).FirstOrDefault();
```

returns a `RCodeComment`.

Comment: Your solution returns "Sequence operators not supported for type 'System.String'." when the linq statement executes.  I think my original statement does return a string and yours is trying to do a firstordefault() on a string value, maybe?

Comment: Ah, I though because of the plural (Comments) it was a collection. If it is a string my solution doesn't make sense at all. So what is the type of `s.Comments`?

Comment: It is a string. The exception is raised on the foreach line above. If I comment out the inside linq statement var RCodeComment = (from s in db.RoomCodesViews... I no longer get any exception, the foreach does exactly what it should. The inside linq statement is affecting the foreach in some manner that I cannot understand. If I run the linq statement var RCodeComment = (from s in db.RoomCodesViews... outside of the foreach loop (using constants instead of variables), it works with out a hitch

Comment: Really weird. What happens if you do `foreach (var ic in RCodes.Select(x => new {x.CodeDescription,x.InspectionCodeId})`?

Comment: We get the same Same Execption (Specified cast is not valid.)

Comment: BTW, someone asked for a stack trace...                                   System.Data.DataTableReader.GetByte(Int32 ordinal) +90
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.Rereader.GetByte(Int32 i) +15
   Read_<>f__AnonymousType0`2(ObjectMaterializer`1 ) +293
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext() +32
   ERAQ.InspectionDetail.fvDetails_PreRender(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\VSSolutions\ERAQ\ERAQ\InspectionDetail.aspx.cs:38
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +9070754
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +31
 (PRERenders, etc..